# Primefaces commandbutton not being called

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I know that there are enough posts about this, but I haven't found the correct answer to my specific problem. Also, I have to admit that I have been working with many programing languages, but I'm new using jsf.

The main problem is that I'm trying to make a form with two p:commandbutton involved. The first one is going to register something, and the other one appears when I popup a dialog.
When I remove the code for showing up the dialog, it works fine, but when I add it, none of the methods are called. Hope you can help me.

```
        <p:dialog id="dlgAgregarProducto" header="Agregar Producto" widgetVar="dlgAgregarProducto" modal="true" width="800" height="300">  
            <h:outputText value="Código"/>   
            <h:inputText value=" "/>
            <h:outputText value="Nombre"/>   
            <h:inputText value=" "/>   
            <p:commandButton id="btnAgregarProducto" value="Agregar" action="#{productoController.agregarProducto}" type="button"/>  

            <p:dataTable id="tblProductos2" value="" 
                         var="prov" 
                         style="margin: 0 auto;"
                         paginator="true" rows="10">

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Código"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Foto"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </p:column>                

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Descripción"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Marca"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Modelo"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:24%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Precio"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>                            
        </p:dialog> 

        <p:commandButton id="registrar" value="Registrar" action="#{promocionController.registrarPromocion}" style="margin-left:370px"/>   
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Try to reduce the amount of code to a minimal example!

Comment: Which is the `<p:commandButton>` that doesn't work?

Comment: none of them. It's kind of curious because when I remove the p:dialog block the last <p:commandButton> works fine

Comment: Move the `<p:dialog>` to another `<h:form>` below the current form in your page. It must be like `<h:form> ... content... </h:form> <h:form> ... <p:dialog> content ... </h:form>`

Comment: no sé porqué hablamos en inglés si ambos somos de lima jaja

Comment: Bueno, el lenguaje oficial de stackoverflow es el inglés y tiendo a respetar esa regla. Por otro lado, si quieres responder en un comentario a una persona, utiliza `@ign` por ejemplo `@Thor` o `@LuiggiMendoza`.